# Twisted unittest "Reactor Unclean" when using TimeoutMixin

Tags: python, unit-testing, twisted, deferred, twisted.internet

I'm implementing a protocol which may be instantiated with different timeouts, so I use `TimeoutMixin`. The idea can be represented with this dummy class:

*my_protocol.py*

```py
from twisted.protocols import basic, policies
from twisted.internet import protocol

class MyProtocol(basic.LineReceiver, policies.TimeoutMixin):
    def __init__(self, timeout):
        self.setTimeout(timeout)

    def lineReceived(self, line):
        self.transport.write(line)
```

To test it with the Twisted Trial a made this unittest roughly following the [official tutorial](https://twistedmatrix.com/documents/current/core/howto/trial.html):

*test_my_protocol.py*

```
from twisted.trial import unittest
from twisted.test import proto_helpers

import my_protocol

class TestMyProtocol(unittest.TestCase):
    def setUp(self):
        self.protocol = my_protocol.MyProtocol(1)
        self.transport = proto_helpers.StringTransport()
        self.protocol.makeConnection(self.transport)

    def test_echo(self):
        self.protocol.lineReceived(b"test")
        self.assertEqual(self.transport.value(), b"test")

    def tearDown(self):
        self.protocol.transport.loseConnection()
```

I get the following error when running the test:

```
$ python -m twisted.trial test_my_protocol
test_my_protocol
  TestMyProtocol
    test_echo ...                                                       [ERROR]

===============================================================================
[ERROR]
Traceback (most recent call last):
Failure: twisted.trial.util.DirtyReactorAggregateError: Reactor was unclean.
DelayedCalls: (set twisted.internet.base.DelayedCall.debug = True to debug)
<DelayedCall 0x7ff1f9a8d070 [0.9994857311248779s] called=0 cancelled=0 TimeoutMixin.__timedOut()>

test_my_protocol.TestMyProtocol.test_echo
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Ran 1 tests in 0.011s

FAILED (errors=1)
```

This is what [official docs](https://docs.twistedmatrix.com/en/twisted-20.3.0/core/howto/testing.html) says on the topic:

> Calls to reactor.callLater create IDelayedCall s. These need to be run or cancelled during a test, otherwise they will outlive the test. This would be bad, because they could interfere with a later test, causing confusing failures in unrelated tests! For this reason, Trial checks the reactor to make sure there are no leftover IDelayedCall s in the reactor after a test, and will fail the test if there are. The cleanest and simplest way to make sure this all works is to return a Deferred from your test.

But I can't figure what to do in case of TimeoutMixin.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You've hooked your protocol up to a `proto_helpers.StringTransport`.  In many ways, this is a good thing and beneficial for the tests.  However, one downside is that `StringTransport` doesn't implement `loseConnection` how you might thing.  All it does is record the fact that the method was called.  It does not deliver the notification to your protocol.

Fortunately, there's `StringTransportWithDisconnection` which *does* deliver the notification to the protocol.  If you switch to this, then your protocol's `connectionLost` method will be called.  Then you have one other change required.  `TimeoutMixin` does not automatically cancel its timeout when `connectionLost` is called.  So you need to add a `connectionLost` to your protocol which calls `self.setTimeout(None)`.

Comment: Thanks a lot! With a bit of additional help from docs the test now passes.
After `self.transport = proto_helpers.StringTransportWithDisconnection()` had to add `self.transport.protocol = self.protocol`.